# How do I map an external tool to a hotkey in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, I have external tools defined in Eclipse that I execute regularly. I'd like to save me some time by wiring them to a hotkey. I've done some googling on this and most of the information I've found is from last decade. I'm also fully aware that I can wire a hot key to "Last executed external tool", but that last tool isn't always the same.

How do I wire an external tool defined in Eclipse to a hotkey?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you can bind a key to this, but the [PathTools](https://code.google.com/p/pathtools/) eclipse plugin lets you register a set of custom command lines, which you can select from a menu. If you can bind a key to selecting it from a menu, then that works.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could be helpful to you, http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/88391/
Here you can possible get som help. Coute :" There currently is a command for running the last external tool
See Window>Preferences>Workbench>Keys
It is in the Run/Debug category; Run Last Launched External Tool
By default it is not mapped to a shortcut.
I have it mapped to F9"

Answer (score 0):

I eventually landed on using AutoHotKey to define additional hotkeys to run external tools.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it:

1. In the common settings of the external tool, set the combo box of "Display in Favorites Menu - External Tools"
2. (optional): Organize favorites for a convenient number.
3. Whenever I want to invoke the tool:

   - press **ALT** (for menu bar),
   - then press **r** (for run),
   - then press **e** (for external tools),
   - then press **the number of the favorite**.

   This can be done really fast. It's the closest thing to a hotkey. After 3 days you won't notice the difference...

Comment: I essentially do that with AutoHotKey